# Is there a conflict between smarty and google analytics (prestashop 1.4)

Tags: smarty, prestashop

I'm trying to add a new google analytics event in a form. 
So I have something like this :

```
    <a href="#" name="button1" onclick="dataLayer.push({'event': 'button1-click'});" >Button 1</a>
```

So far, so good. But I get this weird smarty error :

```
     Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template "C:\wamp\www\mycookit/themes/cookit/delivery.tpl" on line 164 "dataLayer.push({'event': 'event_name'});" - Unexpected ": ", expected one of: "}" , " "' in C:\wamp\www\mycookit\tools\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 431
```

Has this ever happened to annyone? Is it prestashop? Is it just me?

I never had any problem doing this on other websites but none of them where on prestashop or smarty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just add a space after { and before } in your onclick event so smarty does not get confused

Comment: That worked like a charm, weirdly because putting {literal} around it just ignored the all bit without firing an error. Thanks

Comment: If only all code debugs were this simple, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the {literal}{/literal} tag as well to prevent smarty from compiling this part of code :

```
{literal}<a href="#" name="button1" onclick="dataLayer.push({'event': 'button1-click'});" >Button 1</a>{/literal}
```